# Tikz node command changes (0,0) position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am trying to preapare a poster with a0poster. I wrote:

```
 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[DarkOrange,rounded corners=20pt] (0,0.5) rectangle (\linewidth,5);
 % \node (myfirstpic) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{EENG_eng.pdf}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

This draws the desired rectangle in the top of the page, but if uncomment the node command, then the rectangle starts (from the left) at the middle of the image.

Any idea what might be going on?

Thank you

Comment: your image is centered around zero. If you don't want that use `anchor=south west` for the node.

Comment: @percusse: You should provide an answer so this can be removed from the unanswered questions.

Comment: Answered my own question with the solution from @percusse. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As @percusse pointed out, the anchor for an image is the center of the image. In order to make the image fit in the page, tikz moves the canvas center.

To keep the origin (0,0) at the bottom left of the canvas, we need to anchor the image to the bottom (south) and left (west).

Then, the code will look like:

```
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[DarkOrange,rounded corners=20pt] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,5);
\node[anchor=south west] (myfirstpic) at (0,0)
                            {\includegraphics[scale=2]{EENG_eng.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```